# Find a non-trivial solution for the Diophantine Equation $17a^4 + 5b^4 = 35c^4$, or show that no non-trivial solutions exist

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

This is a problem on my practice exam for number theory, and we haven't had an example like this in class yet. The question is looking for a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$. I've tried reducing everything (mod 5), but I didn't really figure anything out from that, and I'm not seeing many options for quadratic reciprocity either...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modulo $5$, we can easily conclude that $5\mid a$.  Dividing by $5$, and looking mod $5$ again, we can conclude that $5\mid b$ and $5\mid c$.

The result, that only $(0,0,0)$ is a solution, follows by infinite descent.

---

There also appears to be a descent argument modulo $4$, and another modulo $17$.

Comment: $b^4\equiv 7c^4\equiv 2c^4\pmod{\!5}$ gives $5\mid b,c$ because otherwise $b^4\stackrel{\text{FLT}}\equiv 1\equiv 2c^4\stackrel{\text{FLT}}\equiv 2\pmod{\!5}$, impossible.

Comment: Alright, I understand how 5 divides all the variables, however, I've never had a class where we've used infinite descent, so I probably wouldn't be permitted to present that as an answer

Comment: @eboz713 Infinite descent is just a fancy term for a simple inductive proof or minimality argument.  We can replace $(a,b,c)$ by $(a/5,b/5,c/5)$ for another solution, but if we do this enough times with a nonzero solution, we will eventually have a solution where at least one entry is not divisible by $5$, contradiction.

Comment: @eboz713 Alternatively: prove by induction that if $a,b,c$ are all divisible by $5^k$, then they are all divisible by $5^{k+1}$.  The only integer divisible by an arbitrary number of powers of $5$ is $0$.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much, this helps a lot!

Comment: @user31415 It's not possible to solve this problem with modular arithmetic alone, because $(0,0,0)$ is a solution, and so we cannot eliminate $(n,n,n)$ as a possibility when working modulo $n$.  I believe that infinite descent or some other trick is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

$\bmod 17\!:\:\:\: 17a^4+5b^4-35c^4\equiv 5b^4-c^4\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, 17\mid b,c\,\Rightarrow\, 17\mid a$,

since $5b^4\equiv\{0,3,5,12,14\}$ ([WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sort%5BMap%5BMod%5B5%23%5E4%2C17%5D%26%2C+Range%5B16%5D%5D%5D)), $\ c^4\equiv\{0,1,4,13,16\}\pmod{\!17}$ ([WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sort%5BMap%5BMod%5B%23%5E4%2C17%5D%26%2C+Range%5B16%5D%5D%5D)).

So $(a/17,b/17,c/17)$ gives another integer solution for arbitrary $(a,b,c)$, which is only possible when $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$ (infinite descent). As Slade said, mod $4,5$ too give infinite descent proofs.

Comment: Doesn't this just show that $17 \mid b,c$?  It needs descent to conclude.

Comment: @Slade right, sorry.